# Can chemical energy from food be stored in a battery?

Tags: energy, electricity

Suppose you built a machine that digested food in a similar way as humans do. Would it be possible, in principle, to extract the chemical energy from the digested food, turn it into electricity, and store it in a battery that powers the machine itself? Doesn't matter if it's practical or efficient, I just need to know if it's not something totally impossible. (I asked the same question on Electrical Engineering SE and someone suggested this SE would be more appropriate.)

Comment: A human body **is** such machine, which proves that yes, it is possible, even though it may be beyond our current technical capabilities.

Comment: Biowaste processing plants do exactly this.

Comment: Humans can ride a bicycle connected to a generator that can charge a battery...

Comment: It is probably possible to design an electrode which "respires" but without the oxidative phosphorylation step and could receive electrons from the reduced coenzymes, NADH and FADH2, produced from the reaction, and then we could pair it with another electrode which reduces O2 to H2O. I mean, if microbial fuel cells (which uses bacteria) and fuel cells which uses the oxidation of organic compounds are possible, I don't see how a fuel cell which uses food could not.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enzymatic_biofuel_cell.and http://large.stanford.edu/courses/2014/ph240/ho2/

Comment: As a side note, yes, I know that the human body is a machine that does that, but I thought it was obvious that I meant a human-made machine.

Comment: Does a person eating a bunch of hamburgers pedaling an exercise bike hooked up to a battery charger count? There's probably a more elegant and direct way to do it though but that would involve molecular engineering (aka an artificial synthetic lifeform). And if you have the tech to do that you can also do the reverse: make a lifeform that uses electricity as a power source as synthesizes sugar and other organic molecules from the power when you supply it with hydrogen, carbon, nitrogen, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Three ways to turn chemically stored energy into electricity:

- a fuel cell: While that works fine for hydrogen or methanol, I'm not sure if sugars are possible, and general "food" won't work. Of course you can chemically convert food into hydrogen or alcohol, or into sth. very specially designed to power a *bio*fuel cell.
- dry, burn, run a turbine or steam engine with attached generator, very obvious and simple.
- direct conversion into mechanical energy via an artificial muscle, which powers a generator. Horribly complicated (bio-)chemistry, theoretically possible, because our body does it, too.

Comment: Olympic track cyclist versus 700 W toaster: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S4O5voOCqAQ&fbclid=IwAR0bcckfWY25I5T5Lt3R9eB2Yvm4j-xarjP1qQEkw6gq1RLWHNPOro4k1F8. ;)

Comment: @EdV I had seen that, yea. The energy spent during running a marathon is barely enough to cook a simple meal. ;)

Comment: You would have to find a system that could extract chemical energy from lipids in a similar fashion to biological systems.